# For arm Linux, could threads in user space access virtual address of Kernel space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm

Virtual memory is split two parts. In tradition, 0~3GB is for user space and 3GB~4GB for kernel space.

My question:

Could the thread in user space access memory of kernel space?

For ARM datasheet, the access attribution is in the charge of domain access control register. But in kernel source code,the domain value in page table entry of user space virtual memory is same as kernel space's page table entry.

Comment: I have got the **answer**.The access permission management is still rely on domain and AP field in Page table entry and Domain access control register. Before 2.6.38, the start-up code initialize the DOMAIN_USER by DOMAIN_MANAGER. But in early_trap_init, the system will modify DOMAIN_USER to DOMAIN_CLIENT. And when the domain attribute is DOMAIN_CLIENT, the AP field in Page table entry will be effective. Thanks the following answers.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, your application might access page 0xFFFF0000, as it contains the swi-handler and a couple of other userspace-helpers. So no, the 3/1 split is nothing magical, it's just very easy for the kernel to manage.

Usually the kernel will setup all memory above 3GB to be only accessible by the kernel-domain itself. If a driver needs to share memory between user and kernel-space it will usually provide an mmap interface, which then creates an aliased mapping, so you have two virtual addresses for the same physical address. This only works reliably on VIPT-Cache systems or with a LOT of careful explicit cache flushing. If you don't want this you CAN hack the kernel to make a chunk of memory ABOVE the 3G-split accessible to userspace. But then all userspace applications will share this memory. I've done this once for a special application on a armv5-system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree. You say, virtual address above 3GB could be only **accessible** by _kernel-domain_ itself, and be **blocked** by _user-domain_. Could you please give a brief introduction how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Userspace code getting Kernel memory? The only kernel that ever allowed that was DOS and its archaic friends.
But back to the question, look at this example C code:

```
char c=42;
*c=42;
```

We take one byte (a `char`) and assign it the numeric value 42. We then *dereference* this non-pointer, which will probably try to access the 42nd byte of virtual memory, which is almost definitely not your memory, and, for the sake of this example, Kernel memory. guess what happens when you run this (if you manage to hold the compiler at gunpoint):

```
Segmentation fault
```

Linux has memory protection like any modern operating system. If you try to access the memory of another process, your process will be terminated before it can do anything (other things I'm not so sure about happen with debuggers though). Even if that memory was that of another Userland process, you would still get terminated. I'm almost sure that `root` programs can't access other programs memory, or Kernel memory. The only way to access Kernel memory is to be part of the Kernel, or indirectly through the kernel's cooperation.

Comment: Sufficiently-privileged userspace may open `/dev/kmem` on Linux (if it's configured in) which is kernel virtual memory ;-)

Comment: @ephemient: Really? But sufficiently-privileged still doesn't mean that it's writable, right? Or is "sufficiently-privileged" just running as `root`?

Comment: If the kernel is configured with `CONFIG_DEVKMEM=y` and there are no LSMs (like SELinux) blocking access, having `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` (`root` has all capabilities, and they can be granted to other processes) is sufficient to read and write `/dev/kmem`.  Once upon a time, this is how module loading worked, though that is no longer the case.

Comment: @ephemient: Really? Bizarre. But if you're running a tool in testing with `root` access trying to infiltrate the kernel, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: There are also APIs which share user and kernel-space memory, like packet-mmap, these usually will mmap kernelspace into userspace, using the same physical address, but different virtual addresses. There is currently NO kernel-interface which allows to share the same physical AND virtual-address. But you CAN (and I already did) create kernel-memory which is accessible by all userspace processes. This is a very hacky and arch-specific approach but it was needed for a special application (sharing memory without aliasing issues introduced by VIVT-DCache) in a confined environment.